# Template joomla 2.5 vs. IE

Tags: internet-explorer, joomla, time, incompatibility

i'm Matteo and i have created a web site (www.caelgroup.it) with joomla 2.5. I have customized a default template from joomla but when i open the web site with IE, the site doesn't process in time and the session ends up.  Can someone  help me?. Thank You Very Much

Comment: Apart from the styling being a little different, the site loads fine for me in IE8, FF, Chrome, Opera and Safari. Must be your net

Comment: it is also working with chrome

Comment: well, you are right, this morning IE open my web site, miracle!!! but the happiness is really short because now the template is not like the original but forced...you know why???? Thank You Very Much for your support....Matteo